# Using Casper.js to click on buttons

Tags: javascript, xpath, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am working on a project to scrape data from an e-commerce website. I am trying to implement it using Casper.js. I am trying to iterate through a Nodelist of AngularMaterial buttons, clicking on them will navigate to a new page/state - my objective is to grab the URL generated. I am having struggling with properly firing the click event on buttons and doing it iteratively. The following is what I got so far.

```
casper.start( "http://store.com", function( ) {
    this.echo(this.getTitle( ) );
} );

casper.waitForSelector( '.md-card-image', function( ) { //Going to Home page and waiting for AJAX content to load
    console.log( 'AJAX results loaded' );
    this.echo( this.getTitle( ) );
    var product = this.evaluate( function( ) {
        return document.querySelector('html').outerHTML;

    } ) 

} )



function goToDetails( ) { //Using querySelector to target the buttons I want to nav to.
   var products = document.querySelectorAll( 'button.md-primary.md-button.md-hue-2.md-raised.md-ink-ripple' );

   return products;

}

casper.then( function( ) { //Trying to access the first button, no luck =[
details = this.evaluate( goToDetails );

this.echo( "Second test" );
console.log(details.length);  //length of 30 - for 30 buttons.
  if(casper.exists(  "button.md-primary.md-button.md-hue-2.md-raised.md-ink-ripple"  )){
      this.echo('found')
  }

  this.clickLabel('Details')

  })

});
casper.then(function(){
    casper.waitForSelector('.image-large-preview', function(){
        casper.echo(casper.getCurrentUrl()); //im getting the proper URL here.
    })
    this.back(); // going back to the home page
})
```

This method clicks the first available button, grabs the URL that it gets navigated to, and goes back to the main page. I need to find a way to click on all the buttons one-by-one and grab the URL. Currently trying to find the correct way to target the buttons, 
This is the markup for one of the cards ( out of 30 on the page). I am trying to target the button with the class "class="md-primary md-hue-2 md-raised md-button md-ink-ripple".

```
   <div flex="33" flex-sm="50" flex-xs="50" layout="row" ng-repeat="product in resultsCtrl.products" class="layout-row flex-xs-50 flex-sm-50 flex-33" style="">
        <md-card flex="" ng-click="resultsCtrl.goToDetail( product )" ng-class="{ 'md-whiteframe-3dp': hover }" ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false" class="_md flex" role="button" tabindex="0">
            <img  class="md-card-image" style="padding-top:10px">
            <div layout="row" layout-align="end center" ng-init="condition = resultsCtrl.getCondition( product )" class="label-row layout-align-end-center layout-row">
                <div ng-show="condition.isVisible" ng-class="{ grey: condition.labelColor,  tiny: resultsCtrl.$mdMedia( 'xs' ) }" class="ui label ng-hide grey" aria-hidden="true">New</div>
            </div>
            <md-card-title>

            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-content>
                <div layout="row" layout-align="end end" class="price-sizing layout-align-end-end layout-row">
                    <div class="msrp results-msrp">

                        <span class="value price-strikethrough">
                        $249.99
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <!----><div ng-if="product.products[0].retailPrice.amount">
                        <div>
                            <span class="ui tiny statistic">
                                <span class="value">
                                $79.99
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div><!---->
                </div>

            </md-card-content>
            <md-card-actions layout="column" class="layout-column">
                <button class="md-primary md-hue-2 md-raised md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="resultsCtrl.goToDetail( product )"><span>Details</span></button>
            </md-card-actions>
        </md-card>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can't click on DOM nodes directly. That's what the error says. You always need to use either CSS selectors or XPath expressions which match the specific single node you want to click. There is always a way. Some are easier than others, but it all depends on your markup which you haven't shown.

Answer (score 1):

Not really shure where's the Problem, but for the CLick all Button Problem this should help:

```
...

var buttons = casper.getElementsAttribute("button.md-primary.md-button.md-hue-2.md-raised.md-ink-ripple", 'id');
while (buttons.length > 0) {
    button = buttons.pop();
    (function(button) {
        casper.then(function() {
            casper.echo("Button id is " + button);
        });
        casper.then(function() {
            casper.click("#" + button);
        });
        casper.waitForSelector('.selector', function() {
            casper.echo(casper.getCurrentUrl());
        });
    })(button);
}

...
```

Another issue could be that the Ajax stuff is not loaded completely. Just try it with a static wait or waitForResource. 
Sometimes it makes sence to activate an Ajax-Container to load the data.

Comment: The buttons I am trying to target have no ID selectors, I'm just going by that long class because its the selector that grabs all the buttons I want to click. Thanks for the codeblock, i modified it so that it targets by class, but I don't think it will work with class selectors. The script runs once until it gets to the echo("Button id is" + button) statement and stops running.